# Bootstrap scrollspy stuck on one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a wordpress theme based on Bootstrap and I'm trying to add scrollspy's effects to my nav, but it only highlights the first element of my nav went the page is loaded (which is wrong, since its corresponding section in in the middle of the page) and then nothing else happens.

My html:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse text-center span4 scrollspy">
    <ul class="nav text-center">
        <li>
                <a href="#section1" >Section 1</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the JS with which I try to activate Scrollspy:

```
$(document).ready(
    $("body").scrollspy({
        target: ".scrollspy"
    })
)
```

My page is structured as follows:

```
<section id="zero" style="height: 100vh">
   ...
</section>
<section id="section1" style="height: 100vh">
   ...
</section>
<section id="section2" style="height: 100vh">
   ...
</section>
```

Comment: got "pos:rel" on body?

Comment: Yes, I set it in my css

Comment: well if the sections are block, i dunno, but you might try the refresh method (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy-methods) onload or something, maybe you page is taking a moment to "boot up" and SS is missing the boat.

Comment: nope again, I even tried adding a delay, to be sure JS has time...

Answer (score 2):

So I'm not really sure what your navbar looks like as you just posted the nav-collapse part but it looks fine to me.  It may be that you only have 2 sections and if you have a fixed navbar and don't specify the offset your second section may not be reaching the top therefore not triggering the active event.  There may be some issue with your navbar structure as well but I'm not really sure.  It may be the way you are initianting the scrollspy with `$(document).ready(` instead of using `$(document).ready(function(){` but not really sure as they both worked for me in the followig fiddle demo that I posted.  Below is the working code that I used along with a working fiddle.  I have added a smooth scrolling code below the scrollspy initiation script if you would like your scroll to have a smooth transition.  Here is the fiddle that I used and it is working just fine [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/1vbLg0gn/).

And here is the code with the full navbar that I used.

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse scrollspy">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#zero">Section Zero</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>



  <section id="zero" style="height: 100vh;background: #222;">
   ...
  </section>
  <section id="section1" style="height: 100vh;background: #555;">
   ...
  </section>
  <section id="section2" style="height: 100vh;background: #888;">
   ...
  </section>
```

And here is the ready function that I used with the top offset

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').scrollspy({
        target: ".scrollspy", 
        offset: 50
    });   
});
```

Hopefully this helps you figure out where things are going wrong.

Comment: It didn't solve my problem (I decided to give up, I'll put something less fancy in place of scrollspy, I've spent far too much time on this issue), but you answer helped my to put some order in my nav, so thank you anyway.